# Generators of Zp* and p-adic cyclotomic character

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime number. It is known that $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is topologically cyclic.

Now let $\chi_{\mathrm{cyclo}} : Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p / \mathbb{Q}_p) \to \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ be the $p$-adic cyclotomic character. This character factors through $Gal(\mathbb{Q}_p(\mu_{p^{\infty}} / \mathbb{Q}_p))$ which is also topologically cyclic.

Can I find a topological generator $g$ of $Gal(\mathbb{Q}_p(\mu_{p^{\infty}} / \mathbb{Q}_p))$ such that the image $\chi_{\mathrm{cyclo}}(g) \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: I am probably confused, but isn't $\chi_\text{cyclo}$ surjective?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cyclotomic characters induce an isomorphism between $Gal(\mathbb Q_p(\mu_{p^{\infty}})/\mathbb Q_p)$ and $\mathbb Z_p^{\times}$.  So your question is equivalent to asking whether there is a topological generator of $\mathbb Z_p^{\times}$ which lies in $\mathbb N$.

The answer is *yes*: choose any natural number that is a primitive root modulo $p^2$ (and hence modulo $p^n$ for all $n$).

[This was already pointed out in an answer by user8268 that is now deleted.]

Comment: Nice answer. Is it still true if we replace $Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p / \mathbb{Q}_p)$ by $Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p / K)$ where $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is finite ?

Comment: My guess is that the answer is still yes, because the image of Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p / K) by the cyclo. character is an open subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ of the form $\mu \times 1 + p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @user65490: Dear user, The answer is still yes.  We are just looking at an open subgroup of the procyclic group $\mathbb Z_p^{\times}$, so it is again procycic, and a  generator can be taken to be a power of our chosen generator of $\mathbb Z_p^{\times}$.  Now just note that a power of an element of $\mathbb N$ is again in $\mathbb N$.  Regards,